# switch не работает

Tags: javascript

При указании значения переменной x=60 значение y должно быть 160, но выводит почему-то 1060. Как исправить?

```js
'use strict';

let x = 60;
let y;

switch(x) {
    case 30:
        y = x + 10;
    case 60:
        y = x + 100;
    case 90:
        y = x + 1000;
}
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для того, чтобы исполнение кода не проваливалось к следующему case необходимо добавить оператор [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description).

```js
'use strict';

let x = 60;
let y;

switch (x) {
  case 30:
    y = x + 10;
    break;
  case 60:
    y = x + 100;
    break;
  case 90:
    y = x + 1000;
    break;
}
console.log(y)
```